# Physical Motivation for Four-Velocity definition

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, vectors, velocity

I'm bothered with the motivation behind defining a four-velocity. In Schutz's *A First Course in General Relativity*, he uses the concept of a tangent vector at each point of a worldline of a particle given by $x ^\mu = (ct,x,y,z)$. And later he states that

\begin{equation}
U^\mu = \frac{d x^\mu}{d \tau}
\end{equation}

The mathematical explanation I found for using the proper time as the parameter wich all observer agree, but I can't realize what problems we obtain with instead this definition we use the relation

\begin{equation}
U^\mu = \frac{d x^\mu}{dt}
\end{equation}

where $t$ is the measure of time in some inertial frame S.

Comment: I don't think you'd be asking this question in Euclidean space. Consider a curve $\vec{r}(\lambda)=(x(\lambda),y(\lambda),z(\lambda))$. Then one can write the tangent vectors as $\vec{T}(\lambda)=d\vec{r}/d\lambda$. OR we could follow your latter suggestion and use $\vec{T}(\lambda)=d\vec{r}/dx$. The tangent vector will still point the right way but no longer is nicely defined and the definition no longer allows you to rotate in a way that mixes the coordinates up since it singles out $x$.

Comment: Doesn’t the book explain somewhere that the four-velocity is defined that way so that it is a Lorentz four-vector?

Comment: @jacob1729 can u give me some example? I'm pretty confused with this topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Milan already answered the technical problems of your definition.

I would like to point out conceptual problems. We would like the 4-velocity to somehow characterize the movement of an object through spacetime. Conceptually it makes sense to demand, that such quantity should depend only on the quantities that have direct relation to that movement. So bringing some random observer's time that has nothing to do with the movement of the object in would be conceptually weird decision. It makes sense to define 4-velocity as tangent vector to the objects worldline, because this mathematical entity is directly connected with it and thus also with objects movement. Of course, we need some parametrization of the worldline, which would be ideally natural to the worldline/movement itself and does not depend on any external quantities. Since in spacetime, every object has its own clocks, this curve is naturally parametrized by clock of the object itself, that is - by its proper time.

Note, that in this way, you don't need to talk about Lorentz group at all. When I first learned about 4-velocity, the decision to use proper time in the derivative felt to me as random decision just to make some  Lorentz 4-vector. But it actually has deeper geometrical reasons, as I tried to explain.

Comment: Can you recommend some relativity book that explains these topics like you explained?

Comment: @Lil'Gravity not really, but I can give you three books that stand out for me personally.  Misner, Wheeler, Thorne - Gravitation explains general relativity  and differential geometry on very intuitive level - together with physical motivations for most of the math, and Wald - General Relativity is great book for more formal, geometrical approach to see clearly how are the concepts defined abstractly without the need of coordinates system. Then there is Fecko - Differential geometry and Lie groups for physicists, which I consider to be the best textbook on differential geometry.

Answer (score 9):

The first definition transforms as a four-vector:
$\dfrac{dx^{'\mu}}{d \tau} = \Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu} \dfrac{dx^{\nu}}{d \tau}$.

The second definition transforms not quite as a four-vector:
$\dfrac{dx^{'\mu}}{d t'} = \dfrac{dt}{dt'} \Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu} \dfrac{dx^{\nu}}{d t}$.

This makes sense, since in the first definition you divide the differentials of a four-vector (which themselves also transform as a four-vector) by a scalar (invariant under the Lorentz group).